# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306. : mysql connection failed while using node.js (using xampp)

Tags: mysql, node.js, xampp, connection

My code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con=mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"",
    database:"test"
});
con.connect(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("connected");
    console.log(err);
});
```

The error message I get:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/ashwinshah/Desktop/mysqlexperiment/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/ashwinshah/Desktop/mysqlexperiment/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/ashwinshah/Desktop/mysqlexperiment/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ashwinshah/Desktop/mysqlexperiment/mysqldb.js:8:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

Comment: Is MySQL server running on your local machine at port 3306?

Comment: yes it is running at port 3306